# Ratio of two folded normal variates

Tags: distributions, folded-normal-distribution

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two independent folded normal variates. Define :
$$W = \frac{X}{Y}$$

How can we find the cumulative distribution function of $W?$ I will be highly obliged for any suggestions/links/help

Comment: Have a look at this paper: [On the Ratio of Two Folded Normal Distributions](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610920600672229?role=tab&scroll=top&needAccess=true&journalCode=lsta20).

Comment: The independence assumption saves you a lot of work. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Derivation) offers multiple approaches to derive the desired result.

One approach described there leads to the expression

$$p_{W}(w) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |y|p_x(wx)p_y(y)dy.$$

From there plug in your densities and integrate with respect to the support to get the CDF.

Comment: @User1865345 Nice find! The desired result is Theorem 3.1 in the paper.